# Carousel Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

See below screen I have tried to implement this animation using cover flow as we as  Carousel animation but I am not getting same as represented in screen. if any body have done this type of animation please send me the code snippet,

[image]

Comment: have you required this type of output?please check my link image:
[http://s5.postimg.org/caoudnnaf/device_2013_09_18_113134.png]

Comment: NO, i require same out put which i posted. i have tried coverflow also for this.

Comment: i have done this using Cover flow animation. below is the link which i have modify my code and come to little bit close to this animation.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735422/android-gallery-bad-image-overlapping-in-coverflow?rq=1

Comment: refer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18973548/1581328
moreover, it doesnt use "gallery". (it is deprecated since API 16)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem in my app sometime ago, Although I haven't worked on the numbers that you are displaying in bottom right corner of your image, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18973548/2389078) link will provide you the full code for making a gallery like view with center image zoom.

You can also set the images according to the number, that you are showing in bottom right, I am doing this in my code now, but if you can understand the code for gallery, then you can also make the code for showing images according to number also or you can show the number according to image.

Comment: This would be modified up to his required maybe, but would not suit if you have lots of images... You need to reuse imageviews somehow, and that's a lot of work.

Comment: Reusing imageViews is really a lot of work and also, on today's android devices, creating imageViews dynamically is quite fast and also, this is the only way I have found to accomplish the task, If you have any other work around, please do tell, I'll also try that.

Comment: I know it is a lot work, that's why probably noone developes that :) And also it is of course quite fast creating and displaying images with imageView but the problem is that you use them in ScrollView which means you create a lot of object and images -assuming that you have a lot picture to display- and that will produce outOfMemoryError eventually. Maybe you can try to modify this library: https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

Comment: Ah!, thanx for the link, I'll surely try to edit the library according to above mentioned task in question. Many people are stuck in same type of problem in android and yes you are right about ourOfMemoryError. So surely, I'll see what I can do. Cheers...

Comment: No problem, i was also having the same problem and hoping to develop some day a global library as carousel but had no time so far :D

Comment: haha, Same here...stuck in projects. But this is the task I'll do for sure.

Comment: Inform me when you do it, i'll use it for sure :)

Comment: yeah sure, why not.. That'll be my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice solution https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow.
I've tried it on Android 4.4 and 2.3.3

Edited. OK. Link below points on FancyCoverFlow lib . That provides few kinds of carousel animation of images.