# Gallery like view with center image zoom

Tags: android

Here I need a gallery like view  with only three images to be shown at a time on screen. In this the middle image will be larger than the two other images on its sides.

If the user scrolls the view next images will slide on screen as it does in gallery and at a time only three images will be shown out of which the center image should automatically zoom when it is shown on screen and remaining two should be smaller than it.

Here I can't use gallery because it is depreciated in android.

I was able to make a gallery like view with help of viewpager using code on [this link](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1). It shows only three images on screen at a time, which fits my one requirement. But i am not able to get the central image that is visible on screen and zoom it. Although I was able to get the clicked image on screen.

Can someone please tell me where do I need to modify [this](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1) code and what I need to add in it to get the image that is in center from the images shown on screen and zoom it.

*I know that there is no center image on screen according to viewpager and it is just showing three images on screen at a time because of modifications in code.*

I have also tried:-

- GridView with horizontal scroll
- HorizontalScrollView with horizontal linear layout

but viewpager seems to be a better solution, because it stops the scrolling with only three items on screen because of viewpager's inherent properties.

and If someone knows any other method to achieve it, please tell me and I'll try it.

**P.S.** For anyone who wants the full code, I have added it as an answer, which has zoom capability also. *Just few additions in accepted answer.* :)

Comment: did you mean the Film Strip View?

Comment: @ss1271 yes, like film strip view and with automatic zoom for the image that will be in the center of the images that are currently being shown on screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override [setPrimaryItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#setPrimaryItem%28android.view.View,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) in your ViewPager and make the center item bigger.

What was the issue with using a HorizontalScrollView with a LinearLayout? If it's centering you may be able to do something similar to this (assuming you've

```
/**
 * A centering HSV loosely based on http://iotasol.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-custom-horizontal-scroll-view.html
 */
public class CenteringHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR = 10;

    private int mActiveItem;

    private float mPrevScrollX;

    private boolean mStart;

    private int mItemWidth;

    public CenteringHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mItemWidth = 100; // or whatever your item width is.
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getRawX();

        boolean handled = false;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mStart) {
                    mPrevScrollX = x;
                    mStart = false;
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mStart = true;
                int minFactor = mItemWidth / SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR;

                if ((mPrevScrollX - (float) x) > minFactor) {
                    if (mActiveItem < getMaxItemCount() - 1) {
                        mActiveItem = mActiveItem + 1;
                    }
                }
                else if (((float) x - mPrevScrollX) > minFactor) {
                    if (mActiveItem > 0) {
                        mActiveItem = mActiveItem - 1;
                    }
                }

                scrollToActiveItem();

                handled = true;
                break;
        }

        return handled;
    }

    private int getMaxItemCount() {
        return ((LinearLayout) getChildAt(0)).getChildCount();
    }

    private LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
        return (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
    }

    /**
     * Centers the current view the best it can.
     */
    public void centerCurrentItem() {
        if (getMaxItemCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int currentX = getScrollX();
        View targetChild;
        int currentChild = -1;

        do {
            currentChild++;
            targetChild = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(currentChild);
        } while (currentChild < getMaxItemCount() && targetChild.getLeft() < currentX);

        if (mActiveItem != currentChild) {
            mActiveItem = currentChild;
            scrollToActiveItem();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Scrolls the list view to the currently active child.
     */
    private void scrollToActiveItem() {
        int maxItemCount = getMaxItemCount();
        if (maxItemCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int targetItem = Math.min(maxItemCount - 1, mActiveItem);
        targetItem = Math.max(0, targetItem);

        mActiveItem = targetItem;

        // Scroll so that the target child is centered
        View targetView = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem);

        int targetLeft = targetView.getLeft();
        int childWidth = targetView.getRight() - targetLeft;

        int width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int targetScroll = targetLeft - ((width - childWidth) / 2);

        super.smoothScrollTo(targetScroll, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current item and centers it.
     * @param currentItem The new current item.
     */
    public void setCurrentItemAndCenter(int currentItem) {
        mActiveItem = currentItem;
        scrollToActiveItem();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I tried with simple horizontal scroll view. I did not tried this method of horizontal scroll view as extended class, but I am trying it now. Although it is giving some exceptions, can you please put working code, so that I can simply try it out.

Comment: Added a better example that should work and will also handle touch events to ensure there's always a centered item.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, the code you posted works fine, but this for horizontal scroll view which can show an item locked in center, but it does not help in increasing the height and width of image. Although i was able to get current item and currently experimenting on increasing its size. Sorry for inconvenience, I am newbie to android and learning a lot of things. I upvoted your answer and will accept it if I am able to zoom the center image.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, Finally, i was able to increase the size of center image and decrease its size again when it goes away from center. Thanks again for help.

Comment: @hamidp when i use method setCurrentItemAndCenter(int currentItem), and scroll the horizontal view manually with finger, the positon is always wrong. It's seems like the horizontal scroll view position is reset from index 0. Can you guys check on that?

Answer (score 14):

Following code will help you to make a gallery like view which will have center lock. It responds to touch and swipe both. It shows three images on the screen at a time and the center image is zoomed.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CenteringHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private static final int SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR = 10;
    private int mActiveItem;
    private float mPrevScrollX;
    private boolean mStart;
    private int mItemWidth;

    View targetLeft, targetRight;
    ImageView leftImage, rightImage;

    public CenteringHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext=context;
        mItemWidth = 100; // or whatever your item width is.
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getRawX();

        boolean handled = false;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mStart) {
                    mPrevScrollX = x;
                    mStart = false;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mStart = true;
                int minFactor = mItemWidth / SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR;

                if ((mPrevScrollX - (float) x) > minFactor) {
                    if (mActiveItem < getMaxItemCount() - 1) {
                        mActiveItem = mActiveItem + 1;
                    }
                }else if (((float) x - mPrevScrollX) > minFactor) {
                    if (mActiveItem > 0) {
                        mActiveItem = mActiveItem - 1;
                    }
                }

                scrollToActiveItem();

                handled = true;
                break;
        }

        return handled;
    }

    private int getMaxItemCount() {
        return ((LinearLayout) getChildAt(0)).getChildCount();
    }

    private LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
        return (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
    }

    /**
     * Centers the current view the best it can.
     */
    public void centerCurrentItem() {
        if (getMaxItemCount() == 0)
            return;

        int currentX = getScrollX();
        View targetChild;
        int currentChild = -1;

        do {
            currentChild++;
            targetChild = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(currentChild);
        } while (currentChild < getMaxItemCount() && targetChild.getLeft() < currentX);

        if (mActiveItem != currentChild) {
            mActiveItem = currentChild;
            scrollToActiveItem();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Scrolls the list view to the currently active child.
     */
    private void scrollToActiveItem() {
        int maxItemCount = getMaxItemCount();
        if (maxItemCount == 0)
            return;

        int targetItem = Math.min(maxItemCount - 1, mActiveItem);
        targetItem = Math.max(0, targetItem);

        mActiveItem = targetItem;

        // Scroll so that the target child is centered
        View targetView = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem);
    
        ImageView centerImage = (ImageView)targetView;
        int height=300;//set size of centered image
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams flparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height, height);
        centerImage.setLayoutParams(flparams);

        //get the image to left of the centered image
        if((targetItem-1)>=0){
            targetLeft = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem-1);
            leftImage = (ImageView)targetLeft;
            int width=250;//set the size of left image
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,width);
            leftParams.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
            leftImage.setLayoutParams(leftParams);
        }

        //get the image to right of the centered image
        if((targetItem+1)<maxItemCount){
            targetRight = getLinearLayout().getChildAt(targetItem+1);
            rightImage = (ImageView)targetRight;
            int width=250;//set the size of right image
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,width);
            rightParams.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
            rightImage.setLayoutParams(rightParams);
        }
    
        int targetLeft = targetView.getLeft();
        int childWidth = targetView.getRight() - targetLeft;
    
        int width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int targetScroll = targetLeft - ((width - childWidth) / 2);
    
        super.smoothScrollTo(targetScroll, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current item and centers it.
     * @param currentItem The new current item.
     */
    public void setCurrentItemAndCenter(int currentItem) {
        mActiveItem = currentItem;
        scrollToActiveItem();
    }

}
```

In your xml add the horizontal scroll view like follow:-

```
<com.yourpackagename.CenteringHorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/HSVImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Horizontalalternative">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</com.yourpackagename.CenteringHorizontalScrollView>
```

Define a Linear layout in your activity.

```
LinearLayout imageGallery;
```

Then get it as follows:-

```
imageGallery=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearImage);
```

Now you have to add imageView to your LinearLayout. Here I assume that you have images in your drawable folder and you have made an array of ids of your images that you want to add to gallery. So you can do it via following method in your activity:-

```
for(int i=0; i<lengthOfImageIdArray; i++){
    ImageView image=new ImageView(YourActivityName.this);
    image.setBackgroundResource(yourArrayName[i]);
    imageGallery.addView(image);
}
```

**You can also set the width of images dynamically, so that they fit every screen, with only little extra effort.**

Comment: Ya, it's work fine...but i need image like cover flow animation...center image is zoom out and left and right images are below of center image..So can u please help me for that..i m really so much confused.

Comment: In class centeringHorizontalScrollView, please find the code where I am getting center, left and right images. I have commented the lines to help. In that code you can find that I am setting margin. It has four parameters. You can set the top margin in those parameters and by increasing that margin you can also keep you left and right images lower than center

Comment: Please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864772/carousel-animation-in-android

Comment: @DennySharma Nice to know that you are happy to help others, I answered the question.

Comment: @DennySharma I thought I answered your question in my comment. Please explain what you want to know.

Comment: @VishwasSharma: that is awesome. Can you please tell me how to add text/title with each Images?

Comment: @shihab_returns: I have also done it. You'll need to create a relative layout in for loop, in which you'll add a textview and an imageView. After this you'll have to add this relative layout to your imageGallery, like we are doing in for loop. Then you can use relative layout's inherent properties to set the views to top and bottom or one after another. You'll need LayoutParams for this. Remember to change you centeringHorizontalScrollView class, because it'll give class cast exception for converting relative layout to imageview. So you'll also need to get first relative layout in that class.

Comment: and then you'll need to get imageView by getChildAt() method. Only then you'll be able to increase or decrease the size of images. This involves some working around the code. I hope you are able to understand the logic. I can't post whole code in comments, but even if you need help please tell me, I'll see what i can do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41542/discussion-between-shihab-returns-and-vishwas-sharma)

Comment: +1 for your reply Vishwas Sharma.
It's working for me. But I've got a question on this. The scrolling works perfectly fine. When I open a new activity wherein the image gets set on the whole ImageView, but on scrolling, the size of the image does not take the whole image view. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @VikramV I am not able to understand you completely. Do you mean that there is empty space between images when size is increased?

Comment: What I meant was, when you execute this code as it is, the initial image it shows (before scrolling) fits the screen size. Then after scrolling the same image is shrinked. So I thought I'll take inputs from you as to how to retain the same image that fits the whole screen size from you. Can you please help me here?

Comment: @VikramV Please find the code under `//get the image to left of the centered image` and `//get the image to right of the centered image` comments. You'll see the code which is changing the image size for left and right image of centered image. You can set the size of image as you wish in this code.

Comment: Thanks @VishwasSharma. I tried that earlier. But that only resizes the images on the left and right side of the centered image. What I wanted it, the center image to be re-sized and fit the whole screen. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: @VikramV please find `int height=300;//set size of centered image` in your code. This is the size of center image. Try to increase this size and I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44602/discussion-between-vikramv-and-vishwas-sharma)

Comment: I'm trying to find a workaround for obtain my goal, but I've a bit of problems in well-understanding your code. My goal is to have 5 elements in the screen, and not three. So the element num 3 will be the enlarged one. A 'free scroll' (like the default HorizontalScrollView), with the screen's centered element that enlarge only when the scroll stop will be my second goal. I'll really appreciate any help, this thing are getting me crazy! Thank you!

Comment: @jem88 for having 5 elements in screen, you just need to decrease the size of `height` and `width` variables in `CenteringHorizontalScrollView` class. Find them in code and experiment with there values to get the right one and about __free scroll__, well I am also struggling with that. I haven't implemented it yet. You'll have to do it and if you are successful, please also do tell me. Once you implement __free scroll__ only then enlarging the 3rd element when scroll stops is a problem, until then you are good to go.

Comment: @VishwasSharma thanks for your response. I'm working on, I'll let you know what is possible to do!