# android slideshow from url

Tags: android, slideshow

I need to make a horizontal slideshow of images from a URL. I've been searching about and have only found examples with `ViewPager` showing images from the `drawable` directory.

There are so many image-load libraries that I don't know what is appropriate for my project, if Picasso or universal image loader or volley...

I tried a universal image loader but seemed very slow actually loading images.

What I need is to get exactly what this application does, which includes a counter images.

[Here](http://bit.ly/1RZXK43) is the link.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18889131/867591

Comment: For me Android Universal Image Loader works well. maybe you can resize images or upload them on faster server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try picasso. I used it on this app that I published a couple of days ago. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jattcode.mikimedia. Is this what you meant. There's an image slider activity if an ad has more than 1 image.

Comment: you're right Jim! that's exactly the feature that i've been looking for, with one small diference, you have used dots indicators to page images, i need to use a counter like "3...2...1 of 10"

Comment: so you used picasso like imageloader, and for the ui has used viewpager? is there a example out there that i can follow? i'm a newbie handling android code