# How to zoom in/out item(only textview) of Vertical ScrollView in android when scroll Vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to create below layout under which item will scroll vertically. whenever we scroll up or down the centered(28) textview should be zoom in position.i found this link [Gallery like view with center image zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889131/gallery-like-view-with-center-image-zoom/18973548#18973548)  but they scroll horizontally using image based on their requirement. i need vertically scroll only using textview
please let me know if any body know the logic.......

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, thanks to @sanjay kumar had a good question.
After 2 days, I found a best solution for this question.
You can use `RecyclerView` and make sure the `LinearLayoutManager` should like this

```
LinearLayoutManager yourLinearLayout= new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
yourLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
yourLinearLayout.setLayoutManager(yearLayoutManager);
```

The most difficult problem is how can you get the middle Item of recyclerView, well I think you can learn more in this link:
https://github.com/plattysoft/SnappingList

Finally, to make the middle Item bigger than the others. In the RecyclerView's Adapter should be like this

```
public class DateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateAdapter.DateViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<LabelerDate> dateDataList;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PADDING = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 2;
private int selectedItem = -1;

public DateAdapter(ArrayList<Datasource> data, int paddingWidthDate) {
    this.dateDataList = data;
    this.paddingWidthDate = paddingWidthDate;

}
@Override
 public DateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
 //todo
 }


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DateViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Datasource data = dateDataList.get(position);
    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {

                holder.tvDate.setText(String.valueOf(data.valueDate));
                holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgSmall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (position == selectedItem) {
            holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#094673"));
            holder.tvDate.setTextSize(35);
            holder.imgSmall.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textviewbold);

        } else {
            holder.tvDate.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.tvDate.setTextSize(35);
            holder.imgSmall.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
        }
    }
}
public void setSelecteditem(int selecteditem) {
    this.selectedItem = selecteditem;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 //todo
}
public class DateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   //todo
}}
```

After created The recyclerView, adapter and datasource. You can look at the `onBindViewHolder()`. If Item is selected then it's become bigger and change to black. If is not selected it will become Gray. My layout look like yours
[image: This is 3 RecyclerViews]

Answer (score 0):

use this library

[Polidea view library](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view)

Put your TextView into a LinearLayout that lives on a ZoomView.

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <com.polidea.ZoomView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="vertical" >        
                </LinearLayout>

        </com.polidea.ZoomView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: sorry reply to u late...@sach i import project FILE->New->import module located in my drive next i clean and rebuild as well all possible way which define in stack exchange,but not working can u send me working sample of code......

Answer (score 0):

The Polidea custom View didn't work in my case, as is. Had to a add a constructor with `AttributeSet` parameter, because it threw an xml inflation error. Also I had to make the `ScrollView` wrap only the `TextView`.