# Android horizontal interactive image picker

Tags: android

I want to implement something like this:

[image]

I have searched a lot of forums and I found this [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) widget. It's good but it uses `Gallery` widget which was deprecated in API 16. As [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) says you should use `HorizontalScrollView` or `ViewPager` instead. I decided to use `HorizontalScrollView` but I have to implement all functionality myself (for example if you touch any flag, it should scroll there or let's say animating flag's translation) and it's a bit complicated so I was searching again and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889131/gallery-like-view-with-center-image-zoom/18973548#18973548) implementation but is isn't as complex as I described, it is just scrolling and changing size. My question is, do you know some widget or library or do I have to implement it myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can implemnt horizontal  list using  RecyclerView
just make an LinearLayoutManager with Horizontal  Orientation  and attach it to the RecyclerView